# nginx try_files help for static files

Tags: nginx

Say I have a file:

/www/public/mysite/blog/4554/some-page-title.html

How can I get nginx to basically ignore everything after that number (id)

so it actually reads /www/public/mysite/blog/4554.html

So basically if users try to access /blog/[any number]/[any title] they will in fact be delivered /blog/[any number].html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite  "/blog/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/?" /blog/$1.html;

thanks to help from a friend.